# Modify T-SQL Query to include/exclude colums depending on other columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below query, that I need some help modifying. In the below Query I get the number of columns that are not null and the percentage:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.col) as num_not_null, COUNT(v.col) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) * 100 as percent_not_null, COUNT(*) as toltalColsNeedsFilled 
FROM EFP_EmploymentUser t 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (t.ITAdvicedFirst), 
                    (t.ITAdvicedSecond), 
                    (t.ITDepartmentDone), 
                    (t.CFOAdvicedFirst), 
                    (t.CFOInfoProvided), 
                    (t.CFOAdvicedSecond), 
                    (t.CFODone), 
                    (t.EconomyAdviced), 
                    (t.EconomyDone), 
                    (t.AcademyAdviced), 
                    (t.AcademyDone), 
                    (t.PublicatorAdviced), 
                    (t.PublicatorDone), 
                    (t.PortraitAdviced), 
                    (t.PortraitDone), 
                    (t.WhoIsWhoAdviced), 
                    (t.WhoIsWhoDone), 
                    (t.BogportalAdviced), 
                    (t.BogportalDone), 
                    (t.KeyCardAdviced), 
                    (t.KeyCardDone) ) v(col) 
    WHERE ID = '19';
```

This returns in the case of ID 19:

```
num_not_null    percent_not_null    toltalColsNeedsFilled
5               23.809523809500     21
```

But I need to check if the following columns in the same table (Publicator,Bogportal,Academy) are filled with value 'yes', and depending on that I need to include or exclude som of the columns from my above query:

```
i.e.: IF Academy = YES then include t.AcademyAdviced & t.AcademyDone
      IF Publicator= YES then include t.PublicatorDone & t.PortraitAdviced
      IF Bogportal = YES then include t.BogportalAdviced & t.BogportalDone
```

Can anyone help me how to modifying the query to achive this? :-)

Best Regards
Stig

Comment: This is logic for your presentation layer, not the database. Return *all* the columns you might need to your application, and then display only the columns you *actually* need in the application.

Comment: Hi Larnu .. Thanks for your reply .. I get your point, but would have liked to handle it in the SQL Query :-)

Comment: Then you will *have* to use dynamic SQL, and I heavily suggest **against** this. I stand by my point, do this in your application, *not* in the SQL.

Comment: Do you mean you need for the *values* of some other columns to not be included in a calculation you're doing, or do you mean you want to dynamically change the number of columns your query returns?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Aside: Is `ID` really a string? You compare it to one: `'19'` rather than `19`.

Comment: @Caius Jard : No, I mean that IF column [Academy] has the value YES then the query should include [t.AcademyAdviced]  and [t.AcademyDone] .. if column [Academy] does not have the value YES it should not include it.

Comment: Oh, ok.. So the thing you need to appreciate about SQL queries is that columns are like attributes; the number of them doesn't vary depending on conditions of a query, in kinda the same way that for example you don't spontaneously cease to have a name just because your eyes are closed.. You're either going to need to run a different query, or run a query that selects some variable thing, like json, or flip the results so that the columns are rows and vice versa, or just run the same query and have the columns as null if the conditions are right. Why do you want a variable number of columns?

Comment: I need it for statistics on a site, to see if if certain steps has been reach, and how many is left .. the issue lays in that if i.e. Academy has not been checked and given the value YES, then it is not a task that should be completed, and there for the t.AcademyAdviced & t.AcademyDone should not be included in the tasks to complete.

Comment: @Larnu .. I toke your advice and programatically did it in my App, and that works great .. If you would post an answer I would hapilly mark it as an answer .. Thank you :-)

Comment: What I stated were only best for the comments, @Stkol76 . The *real* answer would have been posted how to do this in your application's language; which we can't answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` and `WHERE` predicates to decide which columns to add to the unpivot:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(v.col) as num_not_null, COUNT(v.col) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) * 100 as percent_not_null, COUNT(*) as toltalColsNeedsFilled 
FROM EFP_EmploymentUser t 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT * FROM
           ( VALUES (t.ITAdvicedFirst), 
                    (t.ITAdvicedSecond), 
                    (t.ITDepartmentDone), 
                    (t.CFOAdvicedFirst), 
                    (t.CFOInfoProvided), 
                    (t.CFOAdvicedSecond), 
                    (t.CFODone), 
                    (t.EconomyAdviced), 
                    (t.EconomyDone), 
                    (t.PortraitAdviced), 
                    (t.PortraitDone), 
                    (t.WhoIsWhoAdviced), 
                    (t.WhoIsWhoDone), 
                    (t.KeyCardAdviced), 
                    (t.KeyCardDone) ) v(col)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES (t.AcademyAdviced), (t.AcademyDone) ) v(col)
        WHERE t.Academy = 'YES'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES (t.PublicatorDone), (t.PortraitAdviced) ) v(col)
        WHERE t.Publicator = 'YES'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
        FROM (VALUES (t.BogportalAdviced), (t.BogportalDone ) ) v(col)
        WHERE t.Bogportal = 'YES'
) v

WHERE t.ID = '19';
```